# Returning function and invoking with Promise.all

Tags: javascript

```js
function getMyFunction(data) {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value:', data);
    });
}

const myFunction = getMyFunction('a');
Promise.all([
    myFunction,
]).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

I am expecting `result: here is the value: a` but I instead get `result:  [ [Function] ]`.

Comment: `resolve('here is the value:', data)` resolve takes only one argument, the second one will be ignored.

Comment: And why do you expect that behaviour? Telling by the names you used, you're aware that you're dealing with a function, not with a Promise. So how do you get this expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMyFunction` returns a *function* that returns a promise, so you need to call `myFunction` to get the promise:

```js
const myFunction = getMyFunction('a');
Promise.all([
    myFunction(), // <-- note here
]).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```

Comment: I would like to add that the OP returning an arrow function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: @RaunakMukhia what difference does that make in this instance?

Comment: @charlietfl I mean to clarify that () => {} actually is an arrow function, to clear OP's doubt.

Comment: @RaunakMukhia none of that is relevant here. Please don't add irrelevant comments to answers. It's just adding meaningless and useless noise

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I will keep that in mind. I just wanted to clarify as to why OP is returning a function. And hence why he has to do a function call afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`getMyFunction` does what the name suggests: It gets you a **function**. It doesn't call it. `Promise.all` expects a promise. You'd have to call that function to get the promise.

You probably want it to be `getMyPromise` and have it actually return the promise, rather than a function that will, since the nature of `Promise.all` is that things are running in parallel (I assume you'll have more tha one function; otherwise, no point to `Promise.all` at all):

```js
function getMyPromise(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('here is the value: ' + data);
    });
}

Promise.all([
    getMyPromise('a'),
    getMyPromise('b'),
    getMyPromise('c')
]).then((result) => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
});
```